# How to convert an historical date and time to another timezone in Linux/C?

Tags: c, linux

I have some old dates ( with times ) that I am trying to convert from EST to CET ( eastern standard time to central europe time ).

Is this possible in Linux?  Note that to do this you normally just add 6 hours, BUT things get different around daylight savings changeover because the USA and Europe change to daylight savings time on different dates.  Also to add more confusion, the daylight savings time changeover rules have been different in the past for the USA and Europe.

I only need to go about 10 years back in time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413418/how-to-programatically-convert-a-time-from-one-timezone-to-another-in-c

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is directly using the data and code from the [Time Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).  The data includes historical changes to timezones / daylight saving rules.

Answer (score -1):

What you might want otherwise is the mktime function :

The mktime() function modifies the fields of the tm structure as follows: tm_wday and tm_yday are set to values determined from the contents of the
       other fields; if structure members are outside their valid interval, they will be normalized (so that, for example, 40 October is  changed  into  9
       November);  tm_isdst  is  set  (regardless of its initial value) to a positive value or to 0, respectively, to indicate whether DST is or is not in
       effect at the specified time.  Calling mktime() also sets the external variable tzname with information about the current timezone.
(From the man, DST = daylight saving time).